# logback custom appender with spring data jpa

Tags: logback, spring-logback

I'm try to config a custom appender for logback.  The LogDatabaseAppender is annotated with @Component. however, if Login api(  this.logger.error(MarkerFactory.getMarker("LOGIN"),"user:{} wrong password,", username);) , it shows a error systemLogRepository is null.

SpringBoot : 3.1.0

LogDatabaseAppender class:

```
@Component
public class LogDatabaseAppender<E extends DeferredProcessingAware> extends AppenderBase<E> {


    @Autowired
    private  SystemLogRepository systemLogRepository;


    private Encoder<E> encoder;
    private Layout<E> layout;

    @Override
    protected void append(E eventObject) {
        if (!isStarted()) {
            return;
        }

        try {

            String formattedLogEntry = formatLogEntry(eventObject);
            SystemLog systemLog = QsJson.toBean(formattedLogEntry, SystemLog.class);
            systemLog.setResult(1);
            systemLogRepository.save(systemLog);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            addError("Failed to append event", e);
        }
    }

    private String formatLogEntry(E eventObject) {
        if (encoder != null) {
            return new String(encoder.encode(eventObject));
        } else if (layout != null) {
            return layout.doLayout(eventObject);
        } else {
            return eventObject.toString();
        }
    }

    public Encoder<E> getEncoder() {
        return encoder;
    }

    public void setEncoder(Encoder<E> encoder) {
        this.encoder = encoder;
    }

    public Layout<E> getLayout() {
        return layout;
    }

    public void setLayout(Layout<E> layout) {
        this.layout = layout;
    }

}
```

logback-spring.xml

```
<appender name="CUSTOM_APPENDER" class="com.demo.test.config.LogDatabaseAppender"  >
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
            <fieldNames>
                <timestamp>createdAt</timestamp>
                <level>level</level>
                <marker>type</marker>
                <logger>logger</logger>
                <message>content</message>
            </fieldNames>
        </encoder>

    </appender>

    <logger name="com.demo.test" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CUSTOM_APPENDER" />
        <markers>
            <marker>LOGIN</marker>
            <marker>LOGOUT</marker>
        </markers>
    </logger>
```